# Is there a short way to get any non-empty value from each column and to combine them in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable as you can see on the attached screenshot. I am trying to get one non-empty-cell value from each column. But I couldn't achieve.

[image: TheDataTableSS]

For example;
If I get the first row only, the 'Sektor' info will be lost. Instead, if I only get the second row, the 'OdemeSekli' info will be lost. However, I need them both.

This is just an example for 2 rows data. The total row number depends on the user-search so it may be increase. Also, sometimes some columns can be totally empty. But if all the cells of a column are not empty, the presented values will be identical.

Do you have any simple C# solution to search the columns and get one presented value from each?

This is the way I am using to get the data;

```
var combined = (from b in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                join i in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                on b[1] equals i[0]
                select new
                {
                    TeklifNo = i.Field<string>(1),
                    Tur = i.Field<string>(2),
                    SipNo = b.Field<int>(2),
                    OdemeSekli = b.Field<string>(3),
                    Sektor = b.Field<string>(5)
                 }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Hello. Could you improve your question by posting your code? Bulding a [MCVE] is the best way to let us help you.

Comment: You need a left outer join to get items in table 2 that are not in table one.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Why are some fields empty? And is that right? And if so, what values do you want to get??